# What does a vertical bar "|" (aka pipe) accomplish in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

In the following function, which reverses an array/list:

```
let rec rev l =
  match l with
    [] -> []
  | h::t -> rev t @ [h];;
```

One will notice that there is a pipe `|` before the following line:

```
h::t -> rev t @ [h];;
```

I was wondering if anyone would be kind enough to explain what the purpose of this vertical bar `|` is in OCaml, and perhaps other uses? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example it serves as a pattern separator for a multiple selection statement, sorta like the `case` of a `switch` statement in C like languages.

```
let is_vowel c = match c with 
  'a' | 'e' | 'i' | 'o' | 'u' -> true 
| _ -> false ;; 

function is_vowel(c){
  switch(c){
    case 'a':
    case 'e':
    case 'i':
    case 'o':
    case 'u':
      return true;
    default: 
      return false;
  }
}
```

These 2 pieces of code would generate the same output, however ***this is where the similarity's end***. I found [this](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/oreilly-book/html/book-ora016.html) documentation to be very helpful, it go's more into detail what else you can or cannot do with match.

Other uses of the pipe operator are:

- enumerated type declaration

  - `type typ = N1 | N2 | N3`
- union type declaration

  - `type typ = N1 of typ1 | N2 of typ2`

Comment: Just to confirm, `match` would essentially be the switch of other languages as well in this instance?

Comment: I've updated the answer to clarify, essentially yes.

Answer (score -2):

It separates the pattern match cases.