# What does the | symbol mean in ocaml?

Tags: ocaml

I've looked in the O'Caml documentation but am still wondering, what does the `|` symbol mean or do?

Here's an example of one place where it's used:

```
(function (0, 0) -> "both zero"
          | (0, _) -> "first only zero"
          | (_, 0) -> "second only zero"
          | (_, _) -> "neither zero")
```

But obviously I don't think that encompasses all it's uses.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OCaml |> operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30493644/ocaml-operator)

Comment: or this one? https://stackoverflow.com/a/6150853/600486

Comment: No, these occurrences of `|` are different things.

Comment: @Maëlan I understand there might be different occurrences of |. Is there any explanation for what | might be in general?

Comment: Well, `|` alone is a syntax item that occurs as part of pattern matching or algebraic type definitions (see my answer). Sequences of punctuation-like symbols which include `|`, e.g. `||` or `|>`, are user-definable operators (follow links given by @blurfus).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does a vertical bar "|" (aka pipe) accomplish in OCaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43033932/what-does-a-vertical-bar-aka-pipe-accomplish-in-ocaml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [pattern matching](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/a_first_hour_with_ocaml.html#Pattern-matching) (or “case analysis” in a more mathematical-like language). One of the very basic features of OCaml.

The ASCII symbol `|` is used for separating clauses. It denotes a disjunction of cases, reminiscent of `||` which is the boolean disjunction operator.

Here it is used with the keyword `function`, which means that you build a closure which immediately pattern-matches against its argument (a pair of integers) without first naming it.

---

Definition of [custom sum types](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/a_first_hour_with_ocaml.html#Our-own-data-types) follows a similar syntax, for the analogy with pattern matching. Example:

```ml
(* definition of a sum type
   whose values are EITHER [None] OR [Some_int x]
   where x is an integer: *)
type int_option =
  | None
  | Some_int of int

(* pattern matching on a value of type [int_option]: *)
let add (x_opt : int_option) (y : int) : int =
  match x_opt with
  | None       -> y
  | Some_int x -> x + y
```

Answer (score 1):

After `function` and `match ... with` there appear a series of pattern/expressions pairs. The `|` symbol is used to separate these pairs from each other.

In each pair, the pattern and the expression, in turn, are separated by `->`.

Within a pattern `|` can be used to separate alternative sub-patterns.

```
match x with
| (1 | 3 | 5 | 7) -> "odd"
| _ -> "even"
```

As other commenters are pointing out, `|` can also be combined with other characters to form operator names. That is, OCaml names (for values) can consist of special characters like `|`, `>`, `+` if you define them the right way. (The only thing really is that they need to be parenthesized in the definition.)

Answer (score 1):

In OCaml, `|` is used to separate cases in the [OR-patterns](https://ocaml.org/manual/patterns.html#sss:pat-or) or to separate constructors in a type definition. Patterns in OCaml are ubiquitous and is one of the most important and beautiful feature of the language that complements another feature, [Algebraic Data Types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type).

An algebraic data type is defined [inductively](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_type) as a set of [formation rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formation_rule). For example, we can define a type for figures that are either rectangles, circles, their compositions, or, transpositions, e.g.,

```
type figure = 
  | Rectangle of int * int 
  | Circle of int
  | Composition of figure * figure
  | Transposition of figure
```

The type above defines an infinite set of possible figures. And patterns enable easy analysis of their structure. In a language without patterns, we had to rely on dynamic casts and if/then/else.

Indeed, you can see patterns as a generalization of the if/then/else branching facility that is common to all languages. In if/then/else we are deconstructing boolean, which has only two cases, `true` and `false`.  Moreover, the `true` and `false` values do not bear any additional information. Basically, the meaning of `true` or `false` is defined by its name and nothing else. Our figures example is different, each of the cases of our definition bears extra information, which we want to access, e.g.,

```
let rec area f = match f with
  | Rectangle (w,h) -> w * h
  | Circle r -> 2*r*r + 2*r + 1
  | Composition (l,r) -> area l + area r
  | Transposition f -> area f
```

We can see, that our `match` expression is like a three-way if/then/else that also downcasts each figure to its matching type and gives easy access to the properties of each figure so that we can compute the number of pixels that they occupy. In the languages that lack pattern matching, we will have to rely on the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) to compute the area of our figure.

We can also notice, how the definition of the data type coincides with the pattern-matching expression. Indeed, if the definition declares how the data types are constructed, then the pattern matching defines how the data types are deconstructed.

Also, as a bonus track, the syntax,

```
let foo = function X -> a | Y -> b
```

is a syntactic sugar for,

```
let foo v = match v with X -> a | Y -> b
```